# Submit a form on checkbox click

Tags: jquery

I currently use the following code to submit a form and then insert the result in a div. The form is submitted by pressing a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#create').live ('submit', function() {

$.ajax(
    {

    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data

    type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST

    url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call

    success: function(response)
        { // on success..

        $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV

        }

    });

$('#url').val('');

return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});

$("#content").load("contentpage.php");

});
</script>
```

I would like to change this so that rather than submitting the form with the button, I submit it by clicking a checkbox. Is this possible? There are a lot of forms on the page (and several checkboxes). The one that would need to submit the form is called "submitcheckbox"

Any help would be great...

Ross

Answer (score 1):

Something along

```
$('#submitcheckbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // submit form here with your $.ajax call.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitcheckbox').bind('change', function() {
 document.getElementById('create').submit();
});
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox exposes a `click` event so you would basically change:

```
$('#create').live ('submit', function()
```

into

```
$('#submitcheckbox').live ('click', function()
```

Be aware however, that this will happen with checking AND unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I tried this and something seems to happen as the checkbox does not remember the tick (as though it is being refreshed straight away), however the form data does not seem to be submitting to create.php as defined when I set the form ( <form id="create" method="POST" action="create.php"> ) or the DIV is not correctly updating with the result form that page. Any ideas? This was the only answer that seemed to do anything at all! (although possibly I implemented the other suggestions wrongly).

Comment: You have to switch from using `$(this)` to `$('#create')` in your ajax call, since `$(this)` now represents the checkbox

Comment: Aha, almost there. Thanks! One last thing. Is it possible to tell it to just use the name of the form that the checkbox appears in, rather than hardcode the '#create' name of the form? There are a lot of different forms with different names on the page that all need the same behaviour.

Comment: using the `.parent()` or `.closest()` functions would be a possibility to traverse up from the checkbox. So you would not have to actually hardcode the names. Please refer to http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ for more information

Comment: I was already trying the .closest() function however whatever I tried it seemed to fail. So for example, $(this).serialize(), would be replaced by $(what_here?).closest(what_here?).serialize(), ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
$('#submitcheckbox').bind('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('formid').submit();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To submit Form through `Ajax`, try this

Include `jquery.form.js`.
More detail about this plugin is here http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

And add this script:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){

    $('form[name="form_name"]').ajaxSubmit();

});
```